Can Office Script pass user authentication details to Power Automate flow?
I have the following Office Script in Excel which triggers a Power Automate flow.  It works perfectly, except it only runs with the credentials of the user who owns the flow.
Is it possible to alter this script so that it passes the credentials of the Excel user over to the flow?  My flow uses as "When an HTTP Request is Received" trigger.  I believe the solution involves having an App registered in Azure, API permissions using a Client Secret, Client ID and Tenant ID being passed over to Power Automate somehow.
Here's the script I am currently using, and the data has been anonymized:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
  let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Set the values from the named ranges
  let TeamsURL = workbook.getNamedItem("PAGroupID").getRange().getText();
  let DriveID = workbook.getNamedItem("PADriveID").getRange().getText();
  let Filename = workbook.getNamedItem("PAFilename").getRange().getText();
  let FolderLocation = workbook.getNamedItem("PAFolderLocation").getRange().getText();

  // Build the flowEndpoint URL with the specified values
  let flowEndpoint = `https://prod-176.westeurope.logic.azure.com/workflows/8d381f1a9d8b52e1a163454c8899e01a/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/${TeamsURL}/${DriveID}/${Filename}/${FolderLocation}?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=7SHspPxekAIWqFcxgC6y_tPfjU1jqV6mraNx6GqBpmZ`;

  // Open a GET request to the flow endpoint
  httpRequest.open("GET", flowEndpoint, false);

  // JSON payload with the specified information
  let jsonPayload = '{"emailaddress": "Test@mail.com", "emailSubject": "Test", "emailBody": "Test2"}';

  // Send the HTTP request with the JSON payload
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  httpRequest.send(jsonPayload);

  // Display a message based on whether the request was successful
  if (httpRequest.status === 200 || httpRequest.status === 202) {
    console.log("Flow triggered successfully!");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to trigger the flow. Status Code: " + httpRequest.status + "\nResponse: " + httpRequest.responseText);
  }
}

I have tried using Chat GPT to help modify the script but it's not working.

Check if this helps https://devcodef1.com/news/1214543/office-script-user-credentials-in-power-automate
